# WordPress: Using CloudFlare to redirect to URL based on Country IP

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, ipv6

I've got CloudFlare running on my clients WordPress site. In CloudFlare, I have IP Geolocation on along with IPv6 Compatibility and the Psuedo IPv4 on as well.

What I'm trying to do is get anyone from a Canadian IP address to redirect to the Canadian version of my site. I tried this code in the header.php of my child theme:

```
$country_code = $_SERVER ["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];

if ($country_code=="CA") {
    $link = 'https://ca.example.com';
}
else {
    $link = 'https://example.com';
}

header("location:$link");
exit;
```

But that did created redirect errors on the US side. It did seem to redirect properly in Canada. So how can I make it work where Canadians get the redirect but no one else does?

I also tried this in .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry "(.*)$" Country=$1
RewriteCond %(ENV:Country) CA
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://ca.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now that didn't cause any errors but it also didn't redirect either.

Comment: Hmm. The PHP code attempts to redirect everyone, which is almost certainly not what you want. I'm not sure about the .htaccess. It looks OK at a glance, but I dumped Apache a decade ago (for unrelated reasons)...

Answer (score 1):

Paste this in the functions.php file of your child theme. Worked for me.

```
add_filter( 'after_setup_theme', 'ip_redirect_on_cloudflare', 1);
function ip_redirect_on_cloudflare()
{
    $CFCountry = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY'];

    switch ($CFCountry){
        case "CA":
            wp_redirect( 'https://ca.example.com' );
            exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_redirect() function with template_redirect hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: So should  be something like this   function redirect () { 

If ("your conditions ") {
$url = 'my_url';
wp_redirect ($url);
Exit;

}}

 add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect');

Comment: I tried that, but I don't think the redirect is happening. I know I have to include $country_code = $_SERVER ["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"]; in the mix, and I assume that should be inside of the function, right?